Can react-native-iap renew a canceled subscription on Android, and how does requestSubscription handle active subscription periods?
I am using react-native-iap in my Android app to manage subscriptions through the Google Play Store. I have the following scenario:
A user purchases a monthly subscription with auto-renewal turned on.
After 10 days, the user cancels the subscription. This turns off auto-renewal, but the user still has access to the subscription benefits for the remaining 20 days of the billing cycle.
I want to encourage the user to resubscribe before the subscription expires.
Here are my questions:
Does react-native-iap provide an API to specifically renew a canceled subscription on Google Play Store?
If I use requestSubscription to encourage the user to resubscribe before their current subscription expires, will the new subscription overwrite the remaining 20 days of the current billing period, or will it extend the subscription to start after the current period ends?
I want to ensure that resubscribing does not cause any overlap or loss of the remaining active subscription period.
